# Use Userforms in Excel to input a password automatically when refreshing data

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I've had a good look around and whilst I can find some pieces of the puzzle, I'm struggling to put it all together.

What I want to do is write a macro that clears the filters from a worksheet, asks the user for a password, which the application then uses to refresh the data from a password protected SQL source, before saving as todays date.

The macro for saving as today's date is reasonably easy, and I've done something similar to this already. I think I've cracked the filter issue too.

Where I'm struggling is with the password issue. I have to type in the password around seven times at the moment when I refresh this manually. This is obviously a bit pants, so I'd rather just have the user type it once, then have the macro "remember" this password and input it whenever it's needed.

I understand that I need to call a Userform, which I've created and called PassBox. I've even created a text box in there, which is called PasswordBox and an OK button imaginatively called "OK". it even shows hashmarks instead of the actual password.

Where I fall down is how to get Excel to use the password data. I'm not saving the password locally as this would make it much harder to fix the spreadsheet if someone changes the data and also cause Data Protection issues I'd rather avoid.

I'm assuming that I need to get Excel to store the password string as a value and then repeat that to the SQL Server, but I've no idea how to do it!

Code I have so far:

```
Sub Refresher()
'Refreshes the spreadsheet and copies it with today's date

'Clears all filters

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.ShowAllData


'Calls Password Userform, saves password entered there as a string

'Step 1:

 Call PassBox

'Step 2 : once user hits ok, save string entered in password box for use in SQL servers

'Refreshes Spreadsheet

       ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Step 2 Enter password.


'Saves Spreadsheet

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "+++Location+++" & Format(Date, ddmmyyyy) & ".xls"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this approach is going to be extremely difficult as you'll need API calls to populate the password prompts, assuming you can trap the events that raise them. Can't you use Windows authentication with the SQL db?

Comment: I'm a bit of a newb at all this (if that weren't already obvious from my laughable attempt at code above) and I've no experience whatsoever with SQL other than typing the password into the boxes requested. The passwords are prompted for when refreshing the data as below: (imagine its in a box. Don't know how to put a picture in a comment - sorry!)

Comment: `SQL Server Login:                                                                                                           Server |___________________________|                                                          |_| Use Trusted Connection                                                                                                   Login ID |________________________________________________|                   Password: |________________________________|`

Comment: It's going to be really tricky to do this without either using a different authentication method (so the user will either be allowed access or not based on the current user id) or adding the password to the connection string.

Comment: Bollocks. Thanks for you help anyway mate.

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments have pointed out, it will be somewhat difficult to do this the way you intend to do it. But wouldn't it be possible to code the SQL updates and then use the Form1.txtPasswordBox.Value within the code to get the data?

```
Set conRCServer = New ADODB.Connection
conServer.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
    & "DATA SOURCE=YourSQL_Server; " _
    & "INITIAL CATALOG=DatabaseName; " _
    & "User ID=" & frmCredentials.fldLogin & ";" _
    & "Password=" & frmCredentials.fldPassword
conRCServer.Open
```

So, you present the form frmCredentials to the user and ask for a username and password. Once both is entered and the pair is valid you can update all the SQL data using VBA. Of course, this would mean that you will have to break all direct links of the Excel file to the SQL and all updates would be solely controlled using VBA.

*Note: that there is also the option to mask passwords within textboxes in forms.*